# vb6 Export text to a web page

Tags: vb6

What is required for this code to work is to export text to the web?

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
     
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate App.Path & "\page2.htm"
    objIE.document.getElementById("T1").Value = "blah blah"
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it mean to export text to a webpage? Generate a HTML file? Post a HTML form to a server?

Comment: In your question you need to tell us what error are you getting (if any) and what's expected behaviour. Based on your code, `App.Path` needs to have a value since `objIE.navigate` is expecting a url, for example `objIE.navigate "https://www.w3schools.com/html/page2.htm"`.